# Click multiple images using UIImagePickerController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm not able to take multiple images using the camera. Could you direct me to some code showing how to recall the camera multiple times? Thanks in advance.

Code used:

```
-(void) invokeCamera{ 
//Invoke View for Camera 
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) { 
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES; 
 imagePicker.delegate = self; 
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
[imagePicker release]; 
imagePicker = nil; 
} 
else { 
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera Unavailable" message:@"Requires a camera to take pictures" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
[alert show]; 
[alert release]; 
}

}

 (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 uploadImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
[uploadImage retain]; 
indicatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 170, 170)]; indicatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]; indicatorView.clipsToBounds = YES; //indicatorView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

objIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]; objIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, objIndicatorView.bounds.size.width, objIndicatorView.bounds.size.height); 
[indicatorView addSubview:objIndicatorView];

indicatorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)]; indicatorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 indicatorLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
indicatorLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
indicatorLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
indicatorLabel.text = @"Uploading Image..."; 
[indicatorView addSubview:indicatorLabel];

 [picker.view addSubview:indicatorView];
 [picker.view bringSubviewToFront:indicatorView]; 
[objIndicatorView startAnimating];

 [self performSelector:@selector(closeImagePicker) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
 }

(void)closeImagePicker{

[self formRequest: uploadImage];

if (objIndicatorView != nil) 
{ 
[objIndicatorView stopAnimating];
 [objIndicatorView removeFromSuperview]; 
[objIndicatorView release]; 
objIndicatorView = nil; 
} 
indicatorView.hidden = YES;

if ([respPhotoUpload.msg isEqualToString: @"Image Uploaded"])
 {

 [self invokeCamera];
 }
else 
 { 
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
 }
}
```

Comment: Pls use code formatting next time. So that its in a readable form.

Comment: I am not sure if your code will work and even if it does it certainly will leak memory.

Comment: It works for the first time, but not after that.I'm releasing all memory in dealloc(). Wouldn't that prevent the leaks? How do we invoke the camera repeatedly?

Comment: what do you get after the first time

Comment: The screen with the use and retake button. Screen is frozen.The upload action that has to be performed is successfully executed, but after that the screen freezes

Comment: Do you need the cameraControls. Can't you make your own button to take picture.

Comment: Thats fine, but after that how do it invoke the camera is the question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([respPhotoUpload.msg isEqualToString: @"Image Uploaded"])
 {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 [self invokeCamera];
 }
else 
 { 
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
 }
```

I am not sure. Use your own button to take picture then dismiss the camera once you are done with it and then present again

Comment: I tried calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated and then presenting it again, but its now giving me a blank screen

Comment: Hi All, could any one help me out with some tips? I'm not able to implement the overlay  :(

Comment: it WORKED :-) Thanks 7KV7. Your tip gave the breakthrough!